# What am I doing wrong when I try to install a version of perl using perlbrew on a raspberry pi?

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi, perlbrew

I am trying to install a version of perl on a raspberry pi using perlbrew.  I am getting the following output:

```
    ../lib/warnings.t .................................................. ok

    Test Summary Report
    -------------------
    re/fold_grind.t                                                  (Wstat: 9 Tests: 116 Failed: 0)
      Non-zero wait status: 9
      Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
    Files=2506, Tests=951126, 13788 wallclock secs (2169.34 usr 66.77 sys + 10394.74 cusr 392.13 csys = 13022.98 CPU)
    Result: FAIL
    makefile:854: recipe for target 'test_harness' failed
    make: *** [test_harness] Error 1
    perl-5.25.6 is successfully installed.
    yayster@raspberrypi ~ $ perlbrew list
    yayster@raspberrypi ~ $ perlbrew available | head
      perl-5.25.6
      perl-5.24.0
      perl-5.22.2
      perl-5.20.3
      perl-5.18.4
      perl-5.16.3
      perl-5.14.4
      perl-5.12.5
      perl-5.10.1
      perl-5.8.9
    yayster@raspberrypi ~ $ history | tail -n 5
      516  perlbrew install perl-5.25.6
      517  perlbrew -v install perl-5.25.6
      518  perlbrew list
      519  perlbrew available | head
      520  history | tail -n 5
    yayster@raspberrypi ~ $
```

If anyone could tell me why I am encountering such difficulty, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: 5.25.6 is a brand new development release. It just came out on October 20. Unless you're testing new perl features, you should use the latest stable version, 5.24.0 (or is it 5.24.1?)

Answer (score 3):

`perlbrew` always says `perl-XXX is successfully installed` for some reason, so disregard that message.

As you can clearly see, a test failed, and the installer itself reported a failure (`Result: FAIL`). Someone familiar with the process will also notice the output is missing the long list of names of files being copied characteristic of the actual installation portion of the process.

Your Perl wasn't successfully installed, and it was because of a test failure.

---

To debug failed tests, you can go to the build directory and run the test with the harness, or without for more details.

```
cd "${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}"/build/perl-5.25.6

t/TEST re/fold_grind.t            # With harness.

./perl -Ilib t/re/fold_grind.t    # Show the actual output of the script.
```

(Tests must be run from the base directory, but `TEST`'s argument is a path relative to `t`.)

---

That said, you probably didn't mean to install a development (odd-numbered) version of Perl rather than a stable version. Start by trying to install 5.24.0 instead.